# Syllogistic Logic: Negation of a Categorical Proposition?

Tags: logic, syllogism

I am beginner of logic, and am writing an introduction to logic for a math book. I am of the impression that the three main areas of logic to explain are (in order) syllogistic logic, sentential logic, and predicate logic.

Beginning with syllogistic logic, I state that a syllogism is a collection of three statements, where each statement is in the form of a "categorical proposition". There are exactly four possible categorical propositions:

```
All x are y
All x are not y
Some x are y
Some x are not y
```

One might think of `no x are y` and suggest this as another possible categorical proposition, but I believe this is equivalent to `all x are not y`. Similarly, the statement `no x are not y` is equivalent to `all x are y`. Would this be correct?

Secondly, I know that in sentential logic, every statement has a negation. For example, `¬(P ∨ Q) ≡ ¬P ∧ ¬Q`. However, I noticed that neither the Wikipedia page for [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) nor the Wikipedia page for [Categorical Proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) mention negations, anywhere. It is as if negations of categorical propositions don't exist in Syllogistic logic. However this seems strange to me, because based on my own intuition, I would suggest that each has a negation, which I would choose to be:

```
¬(All x are y)      ≡  Some x are not y
¬(All x are not y)  ≡  Some x are y
¬(Some x are y)     ≡  All x are not y
¬(Some x are not y) ≡  All x are y
```

This only comes from my own intuition. However it seems to me to be correct. However, as I mentioned, none of the Wikipedia pages for Syllogistic Logic, Categorical Propositions, etc. make mention of negations of these statements, as if they do not exist in this system. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Unfortunately, the PhilosophySE does not support LaTex. See this [meta post](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43/latex-webtex-availability) for explanations why requests to add this feature have been denied, as well as for suggestions of convenient alternatives for displaying formulae. I usually just copy and paste unicode symbols from online lists of common mathematical symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I edited my question to change my LaTeX code into HTML symbols.

Comment: I think the term "negation" isn't used the same way in term logic. Look instead at the square of opposition. The contradictory of a categorical proposition would be the same as it's "negation" in modern logic. Modern logic has a heritage that treats logical propositions as algebraic equations, so negating is exactly like multiplying by -1. Term logic generally doesn't acknowledge such a thought process. At least terms such as "logical product" and "logical sum" didn't stick around...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are "missing" [The Traditional Square of Opposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/).

As you say :

> ‘Every S is P’ and ‘Some S is not P’ are contradictories.

The "traditional" symbolization is :

- **SaP** for "all S are P"
- **SeP** for "no S is P"
- **SiP** for "some S is P"
- **SoP** for "some S is not P".

**o** and **i** are the *negations* of **a** and **e** respectively.

Thus : **not SaP** will be "not all S are P" i.e. "some S is not P", which is **SoP**.

The same for **not SeP**, i.e. "not no S is P" i.e. "some S is P", whcih is **SiP**.

---

*Note*

From a modern point of view, the "order" must be :

- sentential logic,
- syllogistic logic,
- predicate logic.

Syllogistic logic is called also *monadic* predicate logic, because it is simply the subset of predicate logic with all predicate letters having "arity" one, i.e.monadic.

The *arity* of a predicate letter is the number of its argument-places.

Thus "... is father of ..." and "... is less than ..." are *dyadic* : arity = 2 (two argument places; usually called : *binary* relations).

Categorical syllogism uses only predicates with one argument place, like "... is a men", "... is mortal"; arity = 1 (one argument place).

This is the reason why we cam "model" it with the language of sets (or *classes*) : "all Man are Mortal" is equivalent to : the set of Men is included into the set of Mortals.

See the first modern mathematical logic textbook :

- David Hilbert & Wilhelm Ackermann, [Principles of Mathematical Logic](http://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&pg=PA44) (2nd ed - 1937).

Comment: Ah - this is quite the perfect answer! Thank you, @Mauro. So would you also say that sentential logic is a "subset" of syllogistic logic, where the "contradictory" of syllogistic logic corresponds to the "negation" of sentential logic? That is, the negation of a categorical proposition is its contradictory from the square of opposition? P.S., thanks for the book recommendation; I've just put it on order through Amazon.

Comment: One other question - I'm a little bit confused what exactly is the predicate... It seems you call "...is mortal" (or in general the phrase, "...are P" in the sentence "all S are P") a predicate. However, the Wikipedia page only refers to the single letter P as the predicate. That is, the descriptive terms are "S" (subject) and "P" (predicate), whereas "all" and "are" are logical terms. Thanks for helping me sort this out.

Comment: Yes, P, S are *predicate letters* in modern logic with *arity*. Thus the "standard" categorical clause of syllogism : "all S are P" is translated in modern logic as "for all x(if S(x), then P(x))". Thus "all Men are Mortal" is translated into "for all x(if x is a Man, then x is Mortal)" or equivalently as "for all x(if Man(x), then Mortal(x))". I'm using both "Man(x)" and "x is a Man" to translate the formal "P(x)".

Comment: About sentential logic, it is usually described first in order to introduce the basic concept, and most of all the *connectives*. But it is correct that we can see it as a subset of predicate logic. Of course, if we read *Barbara* as a sentential formula, it amounts to "if p and q, then r" which of course is not a valid argument at all...

Comment: In addition to *SEP*'s entry on [Aristotle's Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) you can see Günther Patzig, A[ristotle’s Theory of Syllogism](http://www.amazon.com/Aristotles-Theory-Syllogism-Logico-Philological-Analytics/dp/9048183227/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1411921682&sr=8-1&keywords=Patzig+Aristotle%E2%80%99s+Theory+of+Syllogism) (1968).

Comment: Would it be correct to say Sentential Logic ⊂ Syllogistic Logic ⊂ Predicate Logic? Thanks again!

Comment: Syll Logic is in modern terms Monadic Predicate Logic (i.e. Pred Log restricted to predicate letters with only one argument) : so, it is correct to say that Syllogistic Logic ⊂ Predicate Logic. also Sentential Logic ⊂ Predicate Logic is true, because every predicate logic instance of a *tautology* is *valid*.