# Do "No S is P" and "All S are not P" mean the same?

Tags: logic, syllogism

I am reading about categorical syllogism in Copi's Introduction to Logic. I was wondering what differences are between the following statements:

- No S is P.
- All S are not P.

Am I correct that

- Their quantities are both universal, instead of particular?
- Their qualities are both negative, instead of affirmative?
- they mean the same?

Does the book answer my question somewhere?

Comment: Normally(?) they're interchangeable, though "hyperintensionally" they might not be the same. Or, then, intuitionist negation theory might not support the interchange, for example.

Comment: See [Aristotle's Logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/syllogistic-logic-negation-of-a-categorical-proposition) and see also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/syllogistic-logic-negation-of-a-categorical-proposition). Yes, they are both Universal.

Comment: @KristianBerry can you elaborate?

Comment: @Mauro do they mean the same? Why are the two links in your comment the same?

Comment: If some S is P, then, "No S is P," is false. So classically/per the opposition-square, at least, the truth condition of, "No S is P," is the same as of, "All S are not P." Or at least that's my understanding of the matter, qualified by reasons to divest certain vectors of the square of existential import, etc. (again e.g. intuitionism's insight that the absence of a term for the presence of some X is not absolutely the same as the presence of a term for the absence of that X).

Comment: A typo. The first one must be to SEP's entry: Aristotle's Logic.

Comment: They are logically equivalent in the classical logic by the [de Morgan law for quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic): ¬∃x P(x) = ∀x ¬P(x). They do not "mean the same", at least, in the sense that they express something in two different ways (this is what having different "intension" stands for), if we did not make this distinction then all theorems of mathematics would "mean the same" as axioms of set theory. Also, there are non-classical logics where they are not even equivalent.

Comment: @Conifold what are some examples non-classical logics that invalidate the equivalence in question?

Comment: In terms of sets, let the collection of objects having property S be defined as the set we will call A, and let the collection of objects having property P be defined as the set we will call B. Then "No S is P" corresponds to the statement "For all a ∈ A, it is false that a ∈ B". Meanwhile, "All S are not P" corresponds to the identical statement. So their meaning is the same.